# Mono 3.0/Debian/asp.net - Method not found: 'System.Configuration.IConfigurationSectionHandler.Create

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linux, mono

Debian Sid, Mono 3.0. I'm trying to run mvc application (it worked before upgrading mono to 3.0). This is exception thrown:

```
Exception caught during reading the configuration file:
System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Configuration.IConfigurationSectionHandler.Create'.
  at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigSystem.GetSection (System.String configKey) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection (System.String sectionName) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.get_AppSettings () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.WebServer.Apache.Server.get_AppSettings () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.WebServer.Apache.Server+ApplicationSettings..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

I've also found tip to make change in /usr/bin/mod-mono-server4 from:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec /usr/bin/mono $MONO_OPTIONS "/usr/lib/mono/4.0/mod-mono-server4.exe" "$@"
```

To:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec /usr/bin/mono $MONO_OPTIONS "/usr/lib/mono/4.5/mod-mono-server4.exe" "$@"
```

Unfortunatelly, there is no such file: /usr/lib/mono/4.5/mod-mono-server4.exe (no such file in /usr/lib/mono/4.5/ directory).

Do you have any ideas what's wrong? My application is ServiceStack simple webpage and it works on mono 2.10. But it doesn't work anymore after upgrade to 3.0.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add a symbolic link for that file

```
# ln -s /usr/lib/mono/4.0/mod-mono-server4.exe /usr/lib/mono/4.5/mod-mono-server4.exe
```

That way it will still use mod-mono-server4.exe but with the 4.5 dll's

Comment: Thanks, it solves the problem. It seems there is no this symbolic link in debian packages.

Comment: Any idea why this whole process has to be done?  I haven't updated my application to use .NET 4.0 yet, and Mono 3.0 caused my app to break.  Making these changes fixes the issue, but I don't understand why.